# Energy of a state of free particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We know the the normalization of a state of free particle is indeterminate and therefore it doesn't have any physical state or definitive energy.

On the other hand, lets consider a free particle of wave function **$\sin kx$**. The energy of the state can be written as, $\frac{ \hbar^2 k^2}{2m} $. Since, the energy of the state is not k dependent, therefore we can say from the  energy equation, Energy of a state is definite.

The two paragraph seems to me contradicting for the free particles energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a propagating particle of mass $m$. Its energy is $\hbar^2 k^2/2m$ just as you say.

Now ask what is the wavefunction for this particle? Well it depends on the initial conditions. We could start with a tightly localised particle, a particle that is only localised to a quite large region or a particle that is almost completely delocalised. All three are valid solutions to the Schrodinger equation and all three have the same energy of $\hbar^2 k^2/2m$. And of course all three wavefunctions are normalised to a total probability of one.

[image: Wavepackets]

*The diagram shows three gaussian wavepackets $\frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp^{-x^2/a^2}$ with different degrees of localisation all normalised to unity.*

When you say you want your wavefunction to be $\sin\,kx$ you are saying that you want your particle to be be completely delocalised. On my figure above that would correspond to a gaussian with infinite width and zero height. Normalising such a wavepacket is impossible because you end up trying to integrate $\tfrac{1}{\infty}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and that isn't a mathematically valid procedure. This is why it's often said that a free particle state can't be normalised.

But we can approach the completely delocalised particle by using a gaussian wavepacket of the form $\frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp^{-x^2/a^2}$, like the ones shown above, and taking the limit of $a \rightarrow \infty$. Whatever the value of $a$ all these wavepackets are normalised to unity and have the same energy, and that's why we can treat the completely delocalised particle as still being normalised to unity and having the energy $\hbar^2 k^2/2m$.

Comment: So, you are constructing a Gaussian wave packet by superimposing with a different wave-function with different  values of k,  which  would be normalized and therefore, will have a definite energy?

Comment: @SabbirHasan: basically yes, though note that strictly speaking a wavepacket for a free particle would be something like $\Psi(x,t) = \int A(k) \exp^{i(kx-\omega t)}dk$, where in this case the function $A$ is the Fourier transform of our gaussian. The resulting wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ does have an expectation value for the energy (given by $\langle\Psi|H|\Psi\rangle$) and can be normalised.